# Getting current interface orientation in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I do the orientation checking dynamically in iOS 5.x as below:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
 if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||interfaceOrientation ==         UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
 {
self.viewProfile.frame = CGRectMake(238, 612, 295, 73);
// some more settings
}
else
{
self.profileNew.frame = CGRectMake(374, 540, 295, 58);
 // some more settings
}
 return YES;
}
```

For iOS 6, I did the below code but thats not working:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{    
   return YES;
}

-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
 if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) 
  {
   self.viewProfile.frame = CGRectMake(238, 612, 295, 73);
   // some more settings
  }
  else
  {
   self.profileNew.frame = CGRectMake(374, 540, 295, 58);
   // some more settings
  }
 return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

How can I check the interface oriention in iOS 6 just like I did in iOS 5.x?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method, where you check the orientation whith

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];`

and set your frames accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: could you please write down the checking conding using [UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]?
ie, if ([UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == "what constant i have to use here")

Comment: It is exactly the same as your's: `if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) { ... } else { ... }`. Another advantage of the  `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is that if you change the frame in there, it will be animated.

Comment: Combined yours and Nikola Kirev's answers and now the code is working properly. Thanks both of you.

Comment: Its my pleasure but I'm new in stackoverflow, how can I do upvote both of you. I already hit "Yes" for Was this post useful to you? which is shown below this comment box.

Answer (score 4):

Try to do the check in this method

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
                            duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Edit:

Use this:

```
BOOL isInPortrait = UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]);
```

Comment: This will call once the app launched and then when we are rotating the device.  I want to check the current orientation from start ie, while we are launching the app without rotating the device.

Comment: checking [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] is not getting correct result. this is enogh : 

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
        if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
                        
        }
        
        else {
           
        }
    }

Combined Levi's and yours answers and now the code is working properly. Thanks both of you.

Comment: Device orientation can be unknown. You need the interface orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Combined Levi's and Nikola Kirev's answers and now the code is working properly. Thanks both of you. Here is the code for others to reference :

For iOS 6 :

```
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
  }


-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
        if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
            self.viewProfile.frame = CGRectMake(238, 612, 295, 73);
            //other codes            
        }

        else {
            self.viewProfile.frame = CGRectMake(374, 462, 295, 58);
            //other codes
        }
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
       }

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
                            duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
        self.viewProfile.frame = CGRectMake(238, 612, 295, 73);
        //other codes
        self.profileNew.frame = CGRectMake(238, 713, 295, 73);            
    }

    else {
        self.viewProfile.frame = CGRectMake(374, 462, 295, 58);
        //other codes
    }
}
```

For iOS 5.x and 4.x

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        self.viewProfile.frame = CGRectMake(238, 612, 295, 73);
        //other codes      
    }

    else {
        self.viewProfile.frame = CGRectMake(374, 462, 295, 58); 
        //other codes
        }
    return YES;
    } 
}
```

Comment: -[UIDevice orientation] returns a UIDeviceOrientation, not a UIInterfaceOrientation

Comment: Yes, I wanted to set interface orientation while changing device orientation.

Comment: They are two different enums. Assigning one to the other will give you unexpected results.

Comment: but I'm not assigning here, just checking. Sorry I'm not arguing with you. I've only 1.8 years exp in iOS and the above code I've used for an app and that was working perfect. here is the app link :
https://itunes.apple.com/app/id544584878

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]
```

Comment: but the constant UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait is not working in iOS 6

Comment: `-[UIDevice orientation]` returns a `UIDeviceOrientation`, not a `UIInterfaceOrientation`